# Lubuntu 14.04 LTS : Freezing cursor

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, lubuntu

When i run youtube clips, my mouse pointer freezes on the screen : it stays at one position, i have to hardboot the system with  + "R,E,I,S,U,B" !

Why does this happen ?
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Having performance issues when running a minimal Ubuntu edition like Lubuntu suggests that you are running Lubuntu on an old computer that has minimal hardware like a slow CPU and a limited amount of RAM. If your computer does not have a graphics card, then the CPU has to do the graphics processing too. If your old computer is a damage case, then your options are limited.

A common cause of mouse cursor freezing is that there are bad sectors in the RAM of the graphics processor while the rest of the RAM continues to work properly. This can cause anything related to graphical output on the screen (e.g. the mouse cursor) to freeze when running a graphics intensive application like watching a YouTube video in a web browser, while other applications that do not use a lot a graphics processor RAM continue to work normally.

Instead of pressing Alt+PrtScr+REISUB, you could try an easier way to regain control of the mouse cursor without rebooting using Ctrl+Alt+L to lock the screen or Ctrl+Alt+Delete to logout, and then log in again. This sometimes works for a while, then if the problem gets worse nothing works except for Alt+PrtScr+REISUB.

I don't like to reboot my computer unnecessarily, so I've made two more custom keyboard shortcuts: 1. Ctrl+Alt+M to minimize all windows showing on the desktop 2. Ctrl+Alt+Backspace to kill the X server. Using these custom keyboard shortcuts helps to collect more granular information when troubleshooting using only the keyboard.

If your computer does not have a discrete graphics processor, then install the Psensor application from the Lubuntu Software Center to check if your computer is overheating. Also install lm-sensors to detect your computer's hardware sensors. Then detect your computer's hardware sensors by opening the terminal and running the command:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Then you will get asked a lot of questions about what hardware you want the program to detect.  It is generally safe and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions, unless you know what you're doing.

In Ubuntu 16.04 Psensor detect your computer's hardware sensors automatically without running `sudo sensors-detect`

Psensor displays itself on the desktop as a little thermometer icon in the notification area in the upper right corner of the desktop. You can right-click the thermometer icon at any time to display the hardware temperatures.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate information and help options !!!